# e2e testing in a nest js with prisma graphql api

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs, prisma

I created a nest js with prisma graphql api. How can i create and run some e2e testing for my api. It would be ideal if i could run my tests against my staging db. Beneath is a starting point i have. But i am not sure where i need to define my prisma service and how i can use it inside my tests.

```
 beforeEach(async () => {
        const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
          imports: [
            UserModule,
            GraphQLModule.forRoot({
              autoSchemaFile: 'src/schema.graphql',
            }),
          ],
        }).compile();

        app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
        await app.init();
      });
```

Kind regards,

Gerry

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to create a `PrismaService` (or another provider with the same name as you normally provide in your server), that consumes a `graphqlconfig` file that was configured for the test environment (i.e. for a test database, whether it's sqlite or a docker based database). Then you can add the `PrismaService` to the `providers` array of the `TestModule`.

**Disclaimer**: I have not done this, just done something similar with a `DatabaseService` in my own application.